# Iterate over a pandas data frame or groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

df_headlines =

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wbZk.png]

I want to group by the `date` column and then count how many times `-1`, `0`, and `1` appear by date and then whichever has the highest count, use that as the `daily_score`.

I started with a `groupby`:

```
df_group = df_headlines.groupby('date')
```

This returns a groupby object and I'm not sure how to work with this given what I want to do above:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4nNj.png]

Can I iterate through this using the following?:

```
for index, row in df_group.iterrows():
    daily_pos = []
    daily_neg = []
    daily_neu = []
```

Comment: `for k,frame in df_headlines.groupby('date')`?

Answer (score 0):

As Ch3steR hinted as a comment, you can iterate through your groups in the following way:

```
for name, group in headlines.groupby('date'):
    daily_pos = len(group[group['score'] == 1])
    daily_neg = len(group[group['score'] == -1])
    daily_neu = len(group[group['score'] == 0])

print(name, daily_pos, daily_neg, daily_neu)
```

For each iteration, the variable `name` will contain a value from the `date` column (e.g. 4/13/20, 4/14/20, 5/13/20), and the variable `group` will contain a dataframe of all rows for the `date` contained in the `name` variable.

Comment: I don't think it is saving the results correctly. For example, have a look at the individual scores for 4/13/20: https://i.imgur.com/zP268kH.png There are two results with a score of `0`. When I run my loop, it shows the length as 1 and not 0: https://i.imgur.com/D4UmAeD.png

Comment: I also tried https://i.imgur.com/PfNLsmU.png in case I wasn't accessing the `score` column in the dataframe in the groupby.

Comment: See my updated answer. `daily_pos`, `daily_neg`, and `daily_neu` contain the count of scores that are +1, -1, and 0.

Comment: That works! Why did it need two groups? The inner group was what you described above - it contains a df of all rows for a given name (date, in this case). So, the outer group is needed to group by the 3 different categories pos, neg and neu?

Comment: `group['score'] == 1` for example, returns a series of boolean values. The outer `group` takes this series of boolean values and returns only the rows that are `True`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df_headlines.groupby("date")["score"].nlargest(1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

No loop required - you will get most common `score` within each group